# How to translate COUNTIFS function in Excel into a SQL query for SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to translate an Excel formula into a SQL query that can work in SQL Server to create a sequence column based on the COUNTIFS function. The Excel formula is =$P2&"-"&IF(OR($Y2=TRUE,$X2=TRUE,$W2=TRUE), 0, COUNTIFS($S$1:$S2,$P2&"FALSE")).

**The formula uses COUNTIFS to count the number of rows that match the pattern %{value in P}FALSE in column S, up to the current row, and combines the count with the value in column P2 to create a sequence value.**

I want the SQL query to return the sequence value for each row as a new column named SEQUENCE.

Here is the SQL query that I have so far:

```
SELECT P2 + '-' + 
    CASE WHEN Y = 1 OR X = 1 OR W = 1
         THEN '0'
         ELSE '???'
    END AS SEQUENCE
FROM myTable
WHERE ???
```

I'm not sure what to put in place of ??? to get the COUNTIFS part of the formula working and return the sequence value as the value for SEQUENCE. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using The `CASE WHEN` Expression With a `SUM()`

Exemple :

```
create table mytable (
  id int,
  pattern varchar(20)
);

insert into mytable values
(1, 'OK'),
(2, 'OK'),
(3, 'NOK');

SELECT 
  SUM(CASE
    WHEN pattern = 'OK' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS COUNT
FROM mytable
```

Result :

```
COUNT
2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN Y = 1 OR X = 1 OR W = 1 THEN 1
        END) AS COUNT
  FROM mytable
```

Count does not include nulls, any rows where the case statement are not true will be null.

Answer (score 0):

To translate the COUNTIFS function from Excel into SQL, you can use a subquery with a WHERE clause to count the number of rows that match the pattern %{value in P}FALSE in column S. Here's the modified SQL query that should work:

```
SELECT P2 + '-' + 
    CASE WHEN Y = 1 OR X = 1 OR W = 1
         THEN '0'
         ELSE CAST(
             (
                 SELECT COUNT(*)
                 FROM myTable t2
                 WHERE t2.P2 = t1.P2 AND t2.S LIKE t1.P2 + '%FALSE'
             ) AS VARCHAR(10))
    END AS SEQUENCE
FROM myTable t1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a windowed count using the `OVER` clause, this allows you to show all rows rather than aggregating.

The exact matching logic is unclear. I've assumed `LIKE '%' +` but you may want just `=`. You also need to specify an ordering column, as SQL tables are inherently unordered sets.

```sql
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    P2,
    '-', 
    CASE WHEN Y = 1 OR X = 1 OR W = 1
         THEN 0
         ELSE COUNT(CASE WHEN S LIKE '%' + P2 + 'FALSE' THEN 1 END)
                OVER (ORDER BY SomeOrderingColumnHere
                      ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    END
  ) AS SEQUENCE
FROM myTable
```